# Unable to translate the given 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it client-side

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I have a list of items "listItems", like this

```
Id Code Value
1  'a'  '1'
2  'a'  '2'
3  'b'  'x'
4  'b'  'y'
```

and to obtain the follwing

```
'a' => '1', '2'
'b' => 'x', 'y'
```

I use the following code by the EF Core

```
public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetAllListsAsync() =>
    await _context.ListItems
            .GroupBy(x => x.Code)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Value)
                                                 .OrderBy(v => v)
                                                 .ToList());
```

I obtain in the Swagger's API the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to translate the given
> 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before 'GroupBy' to evaluate it
> client-side.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression
> extensionExpression)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.ShaperProcessingExpressionVisitor.ProcessShaper(Expression
> shaperExpression, RelationalCommandCache& relationalCommandCache,
> LambdaExpression& relatedDataLoaders)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor.VisitShapedQuery(ShapedQueryExpression
> shapedQueryExpression)

---

What I tried to do:

- If I use AsEnumerable before the GroupBy, it does not find ToDictionaryAsync anymore:
  [image]
- I tested to add `AsQueryable`after the `AsEnumlerable` the compile error message disapeared in compile time, but in runtime remained the same (Unable to translate 'GroupBy' pattern. Call 'AsEnumerable' before ...)
- I tried also this one

  ```
    public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetAllListsAsync() =>
        await _context.ListItems
            .ToLookup(x => x.Code, x => x.Value)
            .AsQueryable()
            .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y)
                                                 .ToList());
  ```

the runtime says in that case:

> The source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement
> 'IAsyncEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,System.String]>'. Only sources that implement 'IAsyncEnumerable' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.AsAsyncEnumerable[TSource](IQueryable`1
> source)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToDictionaryAsync[TSource,TKey,TElement](IQueryable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Did you follow the advice in the error message??

Comment: @ErikEJ it says "can't find ToDictionaryAsync" in that case

Comment: @ErikEJ, and because it is the EF, AsEnumerable will execute the query, before my grouing and ordering...

Comment: Since `ToDictionaryAsync` is an EF extenion method on `IQueryable<TSource>` the easiest  way to keep this awaitable is `.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()`. And yes, `AsEnumerable` will execute the query before grouping, but that's the idea of this operation. But it doesn't *force* execution. The entire statement still has deferred execution.

Comment: @GertArnold I tested `AsEnumlerable` and then `AsQueryable`, the error message disapeared in compile time, but in runtime remained the same (groupby can't be evaluated)

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit too quick commenting. Basically, `.AsEnumerable().AsQueryable()` is a no-op here because the methods only cast (and don't convert).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you load all records, you have to group on the client-side. Note that after materialising objects, you cannot use Async queryable extensions.

```cs
public async Task<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> GetAllListsAsync() =>
   (await _context.ListItems.ToListAsync())
            .GroupBy(x => x.Code)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(y => y.Value)
                                                 .OrderBy(v => v)
                                                 .ToList());
```